# Ruby Join Query Group by Sum particular value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@rentschedule_cc = 
    RentSchedule.joins([{:rent => {:lease => :lease_rent_rolls}}, :charge_code])
                .where("lease_rent_rolls.id = 453861 and
                        rent_schedules.from_date < '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")}' and 
                        rent_schedules.to_date > '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")}' and 
                        rent_schedules.charge_code_id IS NOT NULL")
                .group("charge_codes.charge_type")
```

I am getting the first record in the group-by, but I want the `sum(rent_schedules.annual_psf)` 
and `sum(rent_schedules.monthly_amt)`. How do I get the sum values in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write sum in select

```
@rentschedule_cc = 
    RentSchedule.joins([{:rent => {:lease => :lease_rent_rolls}}, :charge_code])
            .where("lease_rent_rolls.id = 453861 and
                    rent_schedules.from_date < '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")}' and 
                    rent_schedules.to_date > '#{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")}' and 
                    rent_schedules.charge_code_id IS NOT NULL")
            .group("charge_codes.charge_type")
            .select("rent_schedules.*, sum(rent_schedules.annual_psf) as sum1, sum(rent_schedules.monthly_amt) as sum2")
```

and take the `sum1` and `sum2` values in result